# MySQL Joins on n to n relational table keping NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, join, relational-database, left-join

This is a vote system, where candidate can be voted from  different(limited) places. and I want the number of vote per place of each candidate.
I have 3 tables

```
TABLE candidate
------------------
id
name

TABLE place
------------------
id
label

TABLE vote
------------------
id
id_candidate
id_vote
no_votes // represents the amount of votes in this place for that particular candidate
```

Suppose I have 10 candidates and 15 different places, I'm trying to make a query that will return 10*15 = 150 rows even if there is no votes, keeping NULL value for ids that are not present in the relational table(which i can replace by 0).

But i'm not making the correct query
Here is the query i made so far (i've tried many modification, inner, outer joins... but nothing worked)

```
SELECT *
FROM votes
RIGHT JOIN candidate ON  candidate.id =  candidate_id
LEFT JOIN palce ON place.id = place_id
```

Comment: I guess you want LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Can you show us the query you have? You probably need an outer join

Comment: I edited my post. and added my query.

Comment: My suggestion is that you learn about joints and relationships between table. There are plenty tutorials available when you google. This the best way to learn

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want the number of votes per candidate, then you should be thinking "aggregation".

Second, don't mix left and right joins in a query.  It is just confusing.  Start with the table where you want to keep all the rows, and then just use `left join`.

So, something like this:

```
SELECT c.*,
       SUM(p.place_name = 'place1') as place1,
       SUM(p.place_name = 'place2') as place2,
       SUM(p.place_name = 'place3') as place3
FROM candidate c LEFT JOIN
     votes v
     ON c.id =  v.candidate_id LEFT JOIN
     place p
     ON p.id = v.place_id 
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Comment: but my table place has about 300 rows, it's going to be a long query! is that good ?

Comment: If it is what you need to do, then "good" would be an apt adjective.

Answer (score 1):

Considering:

```
TABLE vote
------------------
id                  PK
id_candidate        FK to candidate
id_vote             FK to place
no_votes
```

-

```
SELECT CA.name,
        PL.label,
        SUM(VO.no_votes) as votes

FROM candidate CA
  LEFT JOIN vote VO ON CA.id = VO.id_candidate
  LEFT JOIN place PL ON PL.id = VO.id_vote 

GROUP BY CA.id, PL.id
```